# VMresume failed with unlaunched VMCS, how to deal with it?

Tags: linux, x86, x86-64, virtualization

I am working on a Linux kernel module and a user space program to test VMX.
The code is running in a Ubuntu16.04 laptop with a Broadwell CPU.

The user space program will call kernel module codes to execute VMX instructions to run a testing VM, such as vmxon, vmclear, vmptrld, vmlaunch, vmxoff to vmlaunce the VM, or vmxon, vmptrld, vmresume, vmxoff to resume the VM execution.

After the VMexit (switch back to a user space program to check VM states, then go back to kernel space to continue VMX operations), the module will call vmresume to resume the VM, but vmresume failed with instruction error number of 5, it means 'call vmresume with a non-launched VMCS'.

Then, I changed the code, without switching back to user space, just run the vmlaunch, (vmexit), and vmresume in kernel space (the kernel module), it will work fine.

In order to check the cause of the failure, i changed back to use user space. And use 'sched_setaffinity' to bind all my VMX execution in one CPU core, and dump VMCS on each vmexit, or vmx instruction error.

I still hit this error, even the kernel logs showed these VMX operations are all executed in one CPU, e.g. CPU0. And the VMCS dumping showed almost-empty VMCS after the failure.

I don't know why hit this error with a single VMCS region and binding to a CPU core.

Did I miss something important?

Comment: To make sure that it is not caused by threads migrating between logical processors, I would recommend disabling all but one core (no multicore, no hyperthreading) in BIOS temporarily until you debug and fix the problem.

Comment: Are there other hypervisor modules loaded, e.g. `kvm` or `xen`? `lsmod | grep kvm` and `lsmod | grep xen` should be empty

Comment: It sounds like you are using vmxoff after the vmexit. You need to do vmclear before vmxoff. And after using vmclear with a particular vmcs, you need to use vmlaunch, not vmresume. I suggest that you don’t use vmxoff at all.

Comment: I did NOT find the BIOS options to disable other CPU/cores in this DELL laptop, i will try it further.  
No other hypervisor loaded in the Linux host.  
I found in an IVB laptop (same Linux version), 2 cores (4 threads), the codes work well. But failed in BroadWell (2 cores/4 threads).  
@prl, I called vmxoff only when vmexit and returns to user space. When user space (like QEMU) decides to continue VM, it calls kernel, which then will call vmxon, vmptrld. I will like to test vmresume, avoiding vmclearing to get better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before using vmxoff, you first need to use vmclear on any VMCSes that you want to be able to use again.

Any time you want to resume a VM using a VMCS for which you have done vmclear, you need to use vmlaunch, not vmresume.

So, if you want to use vmresume, you must not do vmclear or vmxoff.

See sections 24.1 and 24.11 of the SDM.

Comment: I just tried your comments, to disable calling vmxoff, it worked!  
I would like to use vmresume to test its functionality.  I used vmxoff when VMExit and it goes to user space to handle that VMExit, to 'protect' errors with VMX on.  But I don't really understand why VMXOFF will touch the VMCS. VMCS is a memory region (may be cached by CPU), I assumed the fields are kept in it, so VMXON, VMPTRLD, VMRESUME, VMXOFF will be safe to resume the VM.  

Do you think VMXON VMPTRLD VMLAUNCH VMPTRST VMXOFF, then VMXON VMPTRLD VMRESUME VMXOFF will work?

Comment: No, vmptrst just saves the address of the VMCS, it doesn’t flush the cache. You really do need vmclear before vmxoff. (But I still don’t suggest using vmxoff as long as you have an active guest.)

Comment: So you mean, i should just call vmxoff on the guest quits, right?  
If so, is there any risk leaving the VMX on during the guest is active, such as doing other operations in kernel and user space?

Comment: I hit another issue when i tried to adjust the code sequence of VMX instructions according to your comments.  Kernel module defines a set of filesystem functions to work with user space. If i set VMXE in CR4 in the device_open, the first call vmlaunch will fail with 'invalid host state', subsequent calls of vmlaunch work fine.   If I set VMXE in CR4 in module_init function, there is no such issue. My host Linux is Ubuntu-16.04, Linux-4.4.0-119 64bit.